# How to migrate keycloak to mysql database and fix timeout after 300 exception

Tags: java, mysql, jboss, wildfly, keycloak

I am trying to setup mysql to my keycloak instance and couldn't get that working due to the following exception:

> Timeout after [300] seconds waiting for service container stability. Operation will roll back. Step that first updated the service container was 'add' at address '[
>           ("core-service" => "management"),
>           ("management-interface" => "http-interface")
>       ]'
>       14:34:42,546 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0190: Step handler org.jboss.as.server.DeployerChainAddHandler$FinalRuntimeStepHandler@65d34517 for operation add-deployer-chains at address [] failed handling operation rollback -- java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
>               at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.waitForRemovals(OperationContextImpl.java:522)
>               at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.handleResult(AbstractOperationContext.java:1518)
>               at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.finalizeInternal(AbstractOperationContext.java:1472)
>               at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.finalizeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:1445)
>               at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.access$400(AbstractOperationContext.java:1319)
>               at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeResultHandlerPhase(AbstractOperationContext.java:876)
>               at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.processStages(AbstractOperationContext.java:726)
>               at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:467)
>               at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1412)
>               at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.boot(ModelControllerImpl.java:521)
>               at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:472)
>               at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:434)
>               at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:435)
>               at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:394)
>               at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:374)
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

```
14:34:42,549 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.client] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0190: Step handler org.jboss.as.server.DeployerChainAddHandler$FinalRuntimeStepHandler@65d34517 for operation add-deployer-chains at address [] failed handling operation rollback -- java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException.
```

https://developer.jboss.org/thread/272010 in this question they also had a similar exception and got it solved after changing **timeout** from **300** to **600**.
but where can i change this setting.

BTW i changed the **transaction timeout** as below but still facing the issue.

```
<coordinator-environment default-timeout="7200" />
```

Comment: Increasing that timeout is likely to lead to other problems.  Please provide the SQL involved in the query.

Answer (score 3):

As most of the people suggested, adding this parameter should do the fix for you.

```
-Djboss.as.management.blocking.timeout=3600
```

Answer (score 0):

I use ubuntu 20.04 LTS on both my desktop and laptop. I noticed that mysql running on the docker container on the laptop while everything was fine on the desktop is running extremely slow, see MySQL [bug#46959](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=46959). If you're having a problem like mine, [this solution](https://phpforus.com/how-to-make-mysql-run-fast-with-ext4-on-ubuntu/) might work.